# How can I subclass (extend) a Java class using Rhino when I need to use a constructor that takes an argument?

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I have a class like the following - this is part of a library and I'm unable to change it at all (if I could, I would just re-write it or subclass it in Java)

```
public class FirstClass
{
   public FirstClass(SecondClass arg)
   {
      ...
   }
   public ThirdClass aMethod()
   {
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

I want to create a Javascript object from that using Rhino (so no comments about JavaScript being different to Java please, I know that) but to override the method "aMethod".

So in Java, I'd do this...

```
public class MySpecialFirstClass extends FirstClass
{
   public FirstClass(SecondClass arg)
   {
      super(arg);
   }
   public ThirdClass aMethod()
   {
      ThirdClass toReturn = super.aMethod();
      //My implementation goes here.
      return toReturn;
   }
   ...
}
```

But I can't seem to do it in Javascript. Things I've tried so far...

```
function js_FirstClass(arg)
{
   var temp = JavaAdaptor(FirstClass, 
      {
         '<init>': FirstClass,
         aMethod: function()
         {
            var toReturn = super.aMethod();
            //Do stuff
            return toReturn;
         }
      });
   return temp;
}
```

I've also tried...

```
var myClass = new FirstClass(secondClass);
myClass.aMethodOld = myClass.aMethod;
myClass.aMethod = function()
{
   var toReturn = aMethodOld();
   //Do stuff
   return toReturn;
}
```

Any more suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Try the prototype approach:

```
function newFirstClass(arg) {
    // Create hidden instance
    var inst = new FirstClass(arg);
    return {
        aMethod: function() {
            var result = inst.aMethod();
            // ... do stuff
            return result;
        }
        // forward every other call directly to inst
        otherMethod: function() {
            return inst.otherMethod();
        }
        // etc...
    }
}
```

So the idea is that you create a JavaScript object which behaves like a `FirstClass` instance by offering the same methods (you need to register each method manually) and passing the calls on to the hidden instance `inst`.

Won't work with `instanceof` but useful if you only need [Duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I hadn't thought of that, however I don't think this will be OK. I get the error "Cannot convert [object Object] to full.path.to.FirstClass"

Comment: As I said: "Won't work with `instanceof`". You're probably passing the instance to some native Java code which expects the real type. This is something which you can't do from Rhino AFAIK. You will have to modify the original Java class (even if you "can't" do this) or at least add a new class to the classpath which inherits from `FirstClass`.

Comment: Yep, I was hoping that there'd be some nice way to override the behaviour, but if not, I'll just give up. I only have access to the JVM via Rhino, adding a class to the classpath is not an option.

Just as a By The Way, I think you're wrong about the `instanceof` being the issue - I think that Rhino complains immediately I call a method because it can't find a method with the signature for the javascript object.

Comment: Rhino or JavaScript doesn't care about signatures. Only the function name is considered (which is why you can't overload in JS). The error message "Cannot convert" means that someone native code expects an instance of type `FirstClass` and Rhino tried to coerce an argument to the expected type - which isn't possible with duck typing.

Comment: Rhino does care about signatures, it has to choose the best one for the item given.

Comment: You're mixing two side: The JavaScript code doesn't care about signatures; JavaScript functions don't have them. Method signatures become important when you cross over to Java. So always be mindful in which context you are.